# gRPC do client options override server options?

Tags: python, grpc

I have a gRPC server implemented in the python API and on it I set several options like so:

```
options=[
      ('grpc.max_send_message_length', 500 * 1024 * 1024),
      ('grpc.max_receive_message_length', 500 * 1024 * 1024),
      ('GRPC_ARG_HTTP2_MAX_PINGS_WITHOUT_DATA', 0),
      ('grpc.keepalive_time_ms', 300000),
]
server = grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4), options=options)
```

We up the default message length to 500 MB from the default of 4 MB.  One of my users is seeing the following error:

```
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: gRPC message exceeds maximum size 4194304: 5224306
```

What I'm trying to figure out is if its possible a client side setting could override my server settings?

Otherwise, is there a problem with the way I'm setting the server options on message length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `grpc.max_{send,receive}_message_length` options on the client and server are enforced locally at each end, independent of each other. So, for example, the client would need to set `grpc.max_receive_message_length` a number like you have here to accept the large messages that the server is sending, no matter what the server settings are.

Comment: The channel options in general are local. They are settings for local behavior, and only a couple directly impact what is sent over the network.